# Can a subdirectory override the parent domain's robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

Context:
sith.edu is mapping the subdirectory sith.edu/rogueone via reverse proxy (/rogueone is using a different CMS and is hosted elsewhere).

My question:
If sith.edu adds disallow /rogueone to their robots.txt, can /rogueone override that effect using their own robots.txt? Or will Google honor the parent domain's robots.txt disallow rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each domain, Google will follow the `robots.txt` at the root of the domain, nothing more and nothing less. Google will be unaware of any reverse proxies.

So if sith.edu adds `disallow /rogueone` to their `robots.txt`, Google will not crawl any of the URLs under `sith.edu/rogueone` (though it could crawl the same *content* at *different* URLs under the real rogueone domain).

In your case, if rogueone changes their `robots.txt`, it will be served up at `sith.edu/rogueone/robots.txt`, and since Google does not recognize `robots.txt` files unless they are at the root of the domain, it cannot change any of the `robots.txt` rules in place for `sith.edu`.